# PWM chip to pin mapping on BeagleBone Black (v4.14)

Tags: beagleboneblack, pwm

There is very little information how to configure the Beaglebone for PWM on newer versions of the kernel. I followed the instructions from [PWM on BeagleBone Black (v4.14)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203064/pwm-on-beaglebone-black-v4-14) to interface with the PWM chips, but now I need to figure out the pin that each chip is connected to.

Based on the Cape Expansion Headers image in the [BeagleBone Black documentation](http://beagleboard.org/support/bone101), I know:

- `EHRPWM0A` = `P9_22`
- `EHRPWM0B` = `P9_21`
- `EHRPWM1A` = `P9_14`
- `EHRPWM1B` = `P9_16`
- `EHRPWM2A` = `P8_19`
- `EHRPWM2B` = `P8_13`
- `ECAP0`    = `P9_42`

When I run `ls -lh /sys/class/pwm` to see the available PWM interfaces I see:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root pwm 0 May  6 14:31 pwmchip0 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300100.ecap/pwm/pwmchip0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root pwm 0 May  6 14:31 pwmchip1 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/48300000.epwmss/48300200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root pwm 0 May  6 14:31 pwmchip3 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/48302000.epwmss/48302200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root pwm 0 May  6 14:31 pwmchip5 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/48304000.epwmss/48304100.ecap/pwm/pwmchip5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root pwm 0 May  6 14:31 pwmchip6 -> ../../devices/platform/ocp/48304000.epwmss/48304200.pwm/pwm/pwmchip6
```

When I compare this to the [BeagleBone PWM example](https://github.com/beagleboard/bb.org-overlays/blob/master/examples/cape-unversal-pwm.txt), I see that the available chips and adresses are different. The example does mention that the PWMs can change, so I need to figure out the new mapping.

**How do I determine the PWM chip to pin mapping?** I am using a TI AM335x BeagleBone Black Wireless running kernel version 4.14.37-ti-r46.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Page 184 of the [TI AM335x and AMIC110 Sitara Processors Technical Reference Manual](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruh73p/spruh73p.pdf) gives the memory map for the PWM chips:

> PWM Subsystem 0: `0x48300000`
>
> - `eCAP0`: `0x48300100`
> - `ePWM0`: `0x48300200`
>
> PWM Subsystem 1: `0x48302000`
>
> - `eCAP1`: `0x48302100`
> - `ePWM1`: `0x48302200`
>
> PWM Subsystem 2: `0x48304000`
>
> - `eCAP2`: `0x48304100`
> - `ePWM2`: `0x48304180`

The address of each PWM interface (posted in the question) contains the hardware address. Matching these addresses gives us:

- `EHRPWM0` (`ePWM0`) is `pwmchip1`
- `EHRPWM1` (`ePWM1`) is `pwmchip3`
- `EHRPWM2` (`ePWM2`) is `pwmchip6`
- `ECAP0` (`eCAP0`) is `pwmchip0`

Each `EHRPWM` chip has two PWM output channels, thus the `A` and `B` variants. They are exported by echoing a `0` or `1` to `export`. These channels must use the same frequency, but can have a different duty cycle.

Therefore, given this interface configuration, `EHRPWM0A` and `EHRPWM0B` are located at:

```
root@beaglebone:~# cd /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip1
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip1# ls
device  export  npwm  power  subsystem  uevent  unexport
```

To export `EHRPWM0A` (`P9_22`):

```
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0# echo 0 > export
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0# ls
device  export  npwm  power  pwm-1:0  subsystem  uevent  unexport
```

To export `EHRPWM0B` (`P9_21`):

```
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0# echo 1 > export
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0# ls
device  export  npwm  power  pwm-1:1  subsystem  uevent  unexport
```

Note: the list of available PWM interfaces and addresses may differ from the list provided in the question, but this method will still work to determine the final pin map.

Comment: The mapping of sysfs names to controllers can change. For example, there is no guarantee that pwmchip0 is EHRPWM0A on all kernel's and device overlays. The only thing that is static is the memory addresses.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken ePWM2 is 0x48304200 and not 0x48304180